# Jquery multiple selects trigger change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a category tree and I am using Jquery on my page to generate a new category select after a previous category has been chosen.

What I need is, if I pass a list of categories (which are ancestors and children of each other), use the code to perform the value selection (which will call the method that I have written previously).

Here is the code that is responsible to fire upon the category change:

```
$(document.body).on('change', '.category-select' ,function(event){

  var select_rank = parseInt($(event.target).attr('rank'));

  var current_category = event.target.value;

  select_category(select_rank, current_category, true)
});
```

When page is rendered there is code that will create the first select. Then on each select change - the select_category function will render a new select (if the category has subcategories).

I am passing a list of categories in an array called cat_list. If it is set, I need the selects to be triggered on last select:

```
if(cat_list != null){
    for(cat_id in cat_list){
        $('.category-select').last().val(cat_id).change();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us some code and what you are try

Comment: There are also many past questions about creating selects that depend on a previous select. Do some searching.

Comment: @MBehtemam I have added the code

Comment: @Barmar I added some clarifications

Comment: Don't use `for-in` to iterate over arrays.

Comment: What's the problem with the code you have? Your question explains poorly what you want to do, but not what you need us to help with.

Comment: @Barmar, you see, I want the code to perform selects instead of me. If there is data in the array, lets say [12, 29, 95]. I want to iterate that array, on first iteration I want to choose the last select with class 'category-select' and choose value 12. That is supposed to trigger all the code I have posted in the first code block which will render a new select with class 'category-select', which will now be the last. On second iteration I want to select in that last select value 29, which is again supposed to trigger the above code and so on.

Comment: @Barmar whats the best way to iterate over arrays?

Comment: `array.forEach(function ...)`, `$.each(array, function ...)`, or `for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { ... }`

Comment: You know that when you use `for (cat_id in cat_list)`, `cat_id` will be the array indexes, not the values, right? It's not like PHP `foreach`.

Comment: So is there any problem you're having other than your misunderstanding of how to iterate over an array?

Comment: @Barmar yes, the select is still empty :(.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @Barmar I have found a workaround with your help. Could you post an answer with mistake in my array so that I could mark is as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not iterating over the array correctly. In your code, `cat_id` is the array index, not the value from the array. Try this:

```
if (cat_list) {
    var last_select = $('.category-select:last');
    $.each(cat_list, function(i, cat_id) {
        last_select.val(cat_id).change();
    });
}
```